# Find and Deletes Duplicates in List of Tuples in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I need to find and remove the duplicates from a List of tuples.
Basically, my structure is made like that:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

****

private void FillStructure()
{
     myList.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "B"));
     myList.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "C"));
     myList.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"));
     myList.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"));    // Duplicate
     myList.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "D"));

     FindAndRemoveDuplicates(myList);
}

private void FindAndRemoveDuplicates(List<Tuple<string, string>> myList)
{
        // how can I perform this ?
}
```

I can't use a Dictionary because I can have the same key but different values!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) method of LINQ, like this:

```
myList = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that this would re-create the list, rather than removing the duplicates in place.

Comment: The solution was so simple! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use HashSet for this purposes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

```
class SameTuplesComparer<T1, T2> : EqualityComparer<Tuple<T1, T2>> 
{
   public override bool Equals(Tuple<T1, T2> t1, Tuple<T1, T2> t2)
   {
      return t1.Item1.Equals(t2.Item1) && t1.Item2.Equals(t2.Item2)
   }


   public override int GetHashCode(Tuple<T1, T2> t)
   {
     return base.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

So if you write your own comparer, you can compare strings a little differently (as example, not casesensetive):

```
class SameStringTuplesComparer: EqualityComparer<Tuple<string, string>> 
{
   public override bool Equals(Tuple<string, string> t1, Tuple<string, string> t2)
   {
      return t1.Item1.Equals(t2.Item1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && t1.Item2.Equals(t2.Item2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
   }


   public override int GetHashCode(Tuple<string, string> t)
   {
     return base.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Then in code:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>(list, new SameTuplesComparer());
```

Or without your own comparer:

```
var hashSet = HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>(list);
```

Now you can add elements to hashSet and all elements will be unique. After you done with adding elements you can convert it to list again:

```
var uniquedList = hashSet.ToList();
```

Or just use `list.Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Do note that you end up with a `HashSet<T>` in this instance and not a `List<T>`. Also a `Tuple<string, string>` won't need a comparer supplying.

Comment: keep in mind that base.GetHashCode() is actually getting the comparer's hashcode instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct()` method:

```
myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that amends the list in place, you can make use of a `HashSet<T>` (or for older frameworks a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, object>` and ignore the value):

```
var existing = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>();

for (int i = myList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (existing.Contains(myList[i]))
    {
        myList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        existing.Add(myList[i]);
    }
}
```

We count backwards without using an iterator (otherwise you'd get errors amending the list while iterating).

`HashSet<T>` also has overloads for overriding equality should you need it.

Personally I'd go for [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275763/358221) for readability.