# Removing duplicates from a list of tuples

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Tuple<string,string>` objects and I want to remove duplicates where, for example, the tuples `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` are considered the same (these are the edges of a graph). What is a *nice* way to do this ?

Comment: Doesn't using the EqualityComparer work, as illustrated in this SO article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275727/find-and-deletes-duplicates-in-list-of-tuples-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you need to preserve the ordering of your tuples, e.g. could you sort them all so that first <= second? That would make it simpler to remove duplicates, e.g. using Distinct as in the answer here.

Comment: No the ordering does not matter

Comment: The solution is almost to make a list of reversed Tuples, and use`Except`.  But the problem is if you have a tuple `("a","b")` and `("b","a")` both in your original list.

Comment: How to do the same thing in Python? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a comparer that can compare tuples in such a way that the order of the items doens't matter:

```
public class UnorderedTupleComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    public UnorderedTupleComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> x, Tuple<T, T> y)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1) && comparer.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2) ||
                comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2) && comparer.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, T> obj)
    {
        return comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Item1) ^ comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Item2);
    }
}
```

Note that an exclusive or of the hash codes is an operation that is going to have the same result regardless of the order of the operands, making it desirable here (but not in most hash code generating algorithms, as it's usually an *undesirable* property).  As for `Equals`, one simply needs to check both possible pairings.

Once you have that you can do:

```
var query = data.Distinct(new UnorderedTupleComparer<string>());
```

Comment: +1 I've created the test program and your algorithm is much faster. The result of clearing the list of 100000 randomly generated Tuples was 3825,1412ms in my case and only 59,5329ms in your case for the same copied list. Deleted my answer.

Comment: comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2) && comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2)

Isn't this the same check?

Comment: @Snaketec Yeah, needs to be the inverse for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<string, string>>`:

```
public class TupleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<string, string> x, Tuple<string, string> y)
    {

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (x.Item1.Equals(y.Item2) && x.Item2.Equals(y.Item1))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return x.Item1.Equals(y.Item1) && x.Item2.Equals(y.Item2);
    }   

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<string, string> tuple)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

You could then use the `Distinct()` LINQ method like this:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { Tuple.Create("a", "b"), Tuple.Create("a", "c"), Tuple.Create("b", "a") };
var result = list.Distinct(new TupleComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a dictionary and making up a key that denotes each tuple.  do you have a character that WON'T appear in your strings, that you can use as a delimiter?  I chose ":" in this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // original list of data
    var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { };
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b"));
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("b", "a"));

    // dictionary to hold unique tuples
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var key1 = string.Concat(item.Item1, ":", item.Item2);
        var key2 = string.Concat(item.Item2, ":", item.Item1);

        // if dict doesnt contain tuple, add it.
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(key1) && !dict.ContainsKey(key2))
            dict.Add(key1, item);
    }

    // print unique tuples
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        var tuple = item.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(tuple.Item1, ":", tuple.Item2));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the original, use [group by](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2013/06/returning-strongly-typed-distinct.html) instead of [Distinct](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2013/06/distinct-nuances.html) so we can still access the first element of the group:

Live code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LYZItb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static List<Tuple<string, string>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
    {
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("B", "A"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "B"), // duplicate
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"), // duplicate
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "D"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("E", "F"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("F", "E"), // duplicate        
    };

    public static void Main()
    {

        var result =
            from y in 
                from x in myList
                select new { Original = x, SortedPair = new[] { x.Item1, x.Item2 }.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray() }  
                group y by new { NormalizedTuple = Tuple.Create<string,string>(y.SortedPair[0], y.SortedPair[1]) } into grp
            select new { Pair = grp.Key.NormalizedTuple, Original = grp.First().Original };


        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pair: {0} {1}", item.Original.Item1, item.Original.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Pair: B A
Pair: C B
Pair: A D
Pair: E F
```

Answer (score -1):

Live Code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LUErFj

Do it by sorting the Tuple pair first, then do a Distinct:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static List<Tuple<string, string>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
    {
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "B"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("B", "A"), // duplicate
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"),
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("C", "B"), // duplicate
        Tuple.Create<string, string>("A", "D")              
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        myList
            .Select(x => new[] { x.Item1, x.Item2 }.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray())
            .Select(x => Tuple.Create<string,string>(x[0], x[1]))
            .Distinct()
            .Dump();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Dumping object(System.Linq.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[Tuple`2[String,String]])
[
   {
   Item1  : A
   Item2  : B
   ToString(): (A, B)
   },
   {
   Item1  : B
   Item2  : C
   ToString(): (B, C)
   },
   {
   Item1  : A
   Item2  : D
   ToString(): (A, D)
   }
]
```

Comment: Note that this can result in a tuple being returned that isn't in the original sequence; if the input is `{"b","a"}` then it'll return `{"a","b"}` and not `{"b","a"}` in the output.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but that's how I understood the question. If it need to preserve the original elements, I'll go back to dotnetfiddle.net and make a second version

Comment: He wants pairs that have the values in the opposite order to be considered equal, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's okay to return an item that isn't in the original set.  It might be fine, but it might not be, it's not defined.

Comment: I like this approach, cause it's simple. But implementing an IEqualityComparer feels like the more "cleaner" solution.